# Keeping a count in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am somewhat new to Java, and working on recursion and binary trees. I have an assignment that loads a very large file and creates a binary tree from each word. In each node, I have stored the word as a String and a frequency int for the number of times the word occurs in the file.

I wrote the program, but for some reason I am getting a number different from what my professor is said that we should get.

```
private int findUniqueWords(Node subTree, int uniqueCount) {

    // Base Case: At the end of the branch
    if(subTree == null){
        return uniqueCount;

    //The word occurs exactly one time
    } else if(subTree.getFreqCount() == 1){

        uniqueCount++;
    }


    //Find the count in the left branches
    uniqueCount = findUniqueWords(subTree.getLchild(), uniqueCount);

    //Find the count in right branches and return
    return findUniqueWords(subTree.getRchild(), uniqueCount);
}
```

As far as I know, this file has loaded into the tree correctly, because all of my other answers in the assignment are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is this a tree of? words? what does getFreqCount do?

Comment: Your code looks fine. You are using recursion here and the logic is right. You can debug your code in eclipse and step by step to see what went wrong. At least the problem is not in this piece of code you pasted here.

Comment: The tree is of words loaded from a file. getFreqCount() is in the Node class and returns the frequency in which the word in the node occurs.

Comment: Ok thanks @BufBills. I actually was scared of that. Now I have no where to take it, and debug mode seems unhelpful because this is a file that includes a book that is over 300 pages long.

Comment: Is it possible that a word appears once in the left subtree and one in the right subtree?  If so, then you would increment uniqueCount twice instead of once.  (I'm not entirely sure how your Binary Tree is handling some of these things.)

Comment: @learned.beh, If the file you used was also used by the professor, and you are both getting different answers, then the only logical solution is that the error is occurring in code you wrote.  Also, eclipse has a step over function that skips over the lines of code that you don't want to watch execute

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that in debug mode. Thanks for the help.